# Linking SDL_image using macOS

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors, codelite, sdl-image

So I'm trying to create a simple 2D game engine with SDL2 and Codelite. I have already written this code and compiled it with gcc, using `g++ src/*.cpp -o game -I include -L lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image` and it didn't work. I have a `lib` folder containing all the libs for `SDL2` and `SDL_image`, and an `include` folder with all the header files of the SDL. I also tried to compile this in Codelite so I recreated the same file structure and I linked SDL. It worked perfectly until I tried to use `SDL_image`. In the `Project settings -> Linker` and `Project settings -> Compiler` tabs, I have put the same paths from where I got the include files and the lib files that I used in my previous project, but it doesn't compile. I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_TIFFClientOpen", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadTIF_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_tif.o)
  "_TIFFClose", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadTIF_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_tif.o)
  "_TIFFGetField", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadTIF_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_tif.o)
  "_TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadTIF_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_tif.o)
  "_WebPDecodeRGBAInto", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadWEBP_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_webp.o)
  "_WebPDecodeRGBInto", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadWEBP_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_webp.o)
  "_WebPGetFeaturesInternal", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadWEBP_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_webp.o)
  "_jpeg_CreateCompress", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_CreateDecompress", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_calc_output_dimensions", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_destroy_compress", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_destroy_decompress", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_finish_compress", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_finish_decompress", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_read_header", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_read_scanlines", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_resync_to_restart", referenced from:
      _IMG_InitJPG in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_set_defaults", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_set_quality", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_start_compress", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_start_decompress", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_std_error", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_jpeg_write_scanlines", referenced from:
      _IMG_SaveJPG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_jpg.o)
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_create_read_struct", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_create_write_struct", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_destroy_read_struct", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_destroy_write_struct", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_get_IHDR", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_get_PLTE", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_get_channels", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_get_io_ptr", referenced from:
      _png_read_data in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
      _png_write_data in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_get_tRNS", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_get_valid", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_read_image", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_read_info", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_read_update_info", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_IHDR", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_PLTE", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_expand", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_gray_to_rgb", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_interlace_handling", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_packing", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_read_fn", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_rows", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_strip_16", referenced from:
      _IMG_LoadPNG_RW in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_tRNS", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_set_write_fn", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
  "_png_write_png", referenced from:
      _IMG_SavePNG_RW_libpng in libSDL2_image.a(IMG_png.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I really don't know where is the problem, because SDL links properly. I use a MacBook Air with M1 processor, macOS Monterey 12.6 and Codelite 16.6.9, which is the latest version I believe. I downloaded it using [the official documentation](https://docs.codelite.org/downloads/download/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way to link SDL on macOS. First, you need to download the DMG installer [here](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/latest). Then you have to copy-paste the folder which is in the installer you just downloaded (the name must be ending in `.framework`, e.g `SDL2.framework`) in `/Library/Frameworks/`. So the path of the `SDL` framework (or any SDL-related framework, e.g `SDL2_image`) will be:
`/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework`. Then, in order to compile your code, you will have to run ths command:

```
g++ main.cpp -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL_image -I include -o mygame
```

This command assumes that all the SDL header files (`SDL.h`) are in the root folder of your project in a folder called `include`. If it is not the case, you can find them in `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL2`.

Comment: Works fine, but you must write `-framework SDL2_image` (with the "2") ;)